# Flutter : Can't load Assets (Audio file particularly)

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player, dart-pub, mobile-development

I am trying to load audio files and play them. But Visual Studio codes open a file named 'asset_bundle.dart' showing this piece of code -

```dart
if (asset == null)
      throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
    return asset;
  }
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml file -

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: 0.15.1

assets:
    - assets/audio/
```

Here's my code -

```dart
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void playSound(String audioPath) {
    AudioCache audioCache = new AudioCache(prefix: 'assets/audio');
    audioCache.play(audioPath);
  }

playSound('swoosh.wav');
```

And the asset folder added in 'pubspec.yaml' lies in the same folder as 'pubspec.yaml' and also it contains 'swoosh.wav' file.

I have tried 'flutter run' command.

Please Help me.

Comment: Your path is incorrect. Try `assets/audio/filename.mp3`. replace `filename.mp3` with your file name.

Comment: I have used prefix in the AudioCache, but I have also tried what you said, this doesn't work.